# Why is preprocessor condition giving me this output

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define Y 10
    int main()
    {
    #if X && Y || Z
    printf ("A\n");
    #else
    printf("B\n");
    #endif
    }
```

Here else is satisfied `B` is printed but if I use

```
#if !X && Y || Z
```

If is satisfied and `A` is printed

My question is, If X and Z isn't defined, how's pre-processor solving the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unresolved symbols in a preprocessor conditional are treated as zeros.  Hence when neither X nor Z is defined, both are treated as zero.

See C11 [§6.10.1 Conditional inclusion ¶4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4):

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

A preprocessing number (or pp-number) is more general than a number in the main language.